# Backup Ubuntu server with RAID

Tags: ubuntu, backup, raid

I saw similar questions, but this a bit different. 
Namely, I am trying to make a backup of Ubuntu server with RAID on it. 
I want to backup complete configuration since that I recently had a problem starting up Server because power-cut messed up partitions and I couldn't start server at all.

I've done same backups with servers before (successfully), but those machines were without RAID and use the following command (from Ubuntu forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087).

```
tar cvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc \
   --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tar.bz2 \
   --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys --exclude-media /
```

I will also exclude a couple of folders on Server (mounted a couple USB HDDs), such as `--/backup_folder1, /backup_folder2`, etc

So, my question is: Am I doing the correct exclusions or making same mistake (simply don't want to find out in a harder way and stop almost entire company because I miseed something)?

Comment: Don't think what your asking should be effected by the fact your using a RAID controller at all.

Comment: You also want to exclude /dev.  Also, unless you have some broken hardware, you can cut the power all day long and not "mess up partitions".  The only thing you should loose is any unsaved work you had at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you ask is not related to RAID at all.

Consider, however, what is really important when backing up a server.

Personally, I would create separate backups of /etc and /var{lib,log,www}, since these could be applied almost as-is to a new server with the same exact OS on it.

As for the rest - a disk image works wonders but increases significantly in value if you don't include any stored data in it, keeping it small.

Your data/content/files/whatever (the things this server actually serves) are probably best protected by running rsync to a remote backup location.

Comment: My mistake for tagging it as RAID, sorry. Idea was to explain problem  which I had. I will do a backup that way. Thanks for quick respond